# Change a program to accept command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I have the following code and would like to modify it to accept command line arguments instead of reading a file using scanner. Can you point me to some change I need to make in the code in order to do so ? Any help is appreciated. I will have a file called prgm.cmd and will execute it on UNIX as follows. prgm.cmd is the actual argument !

```
java Commander prgm.cmd
```

right now I am only able to have the program work by using

```
java Commander < prgm.cmd
```

CODE

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Commander
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String,Integer> expression = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true)
        {
            list.add(sc.nextLine());
            if(!sc.hasNextLine()) break;
        }

        ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> PRINT = new ArrayList<String>();


        for(String element : list) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(element);

            if(!element.startsWith("PRINT")) {
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    tokens.add(st.nextToken());
                }

                expression.put(tokens.get(0),Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(2)));
                tokens.clear();
            } else {
                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                    PRINT.add(st.nextToken());
                System.out.println(expression.get(PRINT.get(1)));
                PRINT.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SAMPLE COMMAND FILE: PRGM.CMD

```
A = 6   
C = 14
PRINT C 
B = 12
C = 8
PRINT A
```

OUTPUT

```
14
 6
```

Comment: The command line arguments will be passed in the `args` parameter to the `main` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When you run your program with something like:

```
java progname arg1 arg2
```

the arguments appear in the string array handed to `main()`. You just extract them from there and do what you need.

The following small (but complete) program shows this in action. It will echo back your arguments, one per line:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            System.out.println (args[i]);
    }
}
```

That's to get the commands as *arguments* to the program.

---

If, instead, you want to still have the commands in a file and just supply the *file name* to the program, you simply need to change your scanner to use a file based reader rather than `System.in`. The following program accepts a file name argument then echos it to the screen:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (new FileInputStream(args[0]));
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
            System.out.println (sc.nextLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can even make it selectable, like UNIX filter programs using `-` to indicate standard input.

If you want to use a file if provided but revert to standard input if not, you can do something like:

```
Scanner sc;
if (args.length > 0)
    sc = new Scanner (new FileInputStream(args[0]));
else
    sc = new Scanner (System.in);

// Now just use scanner as before
```

Comment: I understand but I always seem to get an arrayoutofbounds error, how do I read in an arbitrary number of command line arguments from the file in to the String[] args array ? can i pass an ArrayList instead of String[] to the main ?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm, I've added a small sample which shows you that, you simply ensure you don't go beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Is it possible to simply change System.in to a File object ?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm: yes, I've added an extra bit for that as well.